# Цифровая подпись RSA

Tags: c#, криптография

Здравствуйте, делаю лабораторную работу и никак не могу разобраться как получить вменяемый хэш-образ. В общем суть задачи состоит в
 1. Вычисление хеш-образа h = h(T), где T – исходное сообщение, h(T) – хеш-функция (для MD5 длина хеш-образа 128 бит).

Для примера после сжатия строки в число, получили маленькое число 7. Причем не указан никакой алгоритм для этого, и даже пример строки. В общем дальше нужно будет это число возводить в степень для расчета цифровой подписи. И вот я не понимаю как получить такое число. Я честно говоря знаю ток два метода:

1. Хешированием с помощью MD5. Результат выдается 16ричном виде, что мне совершенно не подходит. Использовал класс System.Security.Cryptography.MD5.
2. обычный метод GetHashCode на стринге. Но там выдаются значения вида -8893475.

Инфы вообще не дали никакой, и я в принципе загуглить не смог, так как не сильно представляю, что именно гуглить. Я понимаю, что может привел недостаточно информации для поста. И вопрос может быть глупый, но буду благодарен, если кто ответит.

В общем сам вопрос, как собственно получить некое число для этого алгоритма (вычислить хеш-сумму или как это правильно назвать)?

Comment: "Результат выдается 16ричном виде" а вам в каком надо? Результат MD5 - 4 DWORD'а, или те самые 128 бит.

Comment: мне нужно этот результат использовать в формуле
 Выработка цифровой подписи s = h^d mod n, где d – закрытый.

Comment: И в чем проблема? У вас есть 16 байт хэша, считайте что это число.

Comment: Я не понимаю, как мне использовать результат MD5(например 026f8e459c8f89ef75fa7a78265a0025). Или его сначала в число надо конвертнуть. Просто дальше мне же его по формуле нужно в степень возвести.

Comment: Вы собираетесь в степень руками возводить? Или вы уже выбрали функцию возведения в степень по модулю?

Comment: нет я имею ввиду. Как мне получить хеш образ в виде некоторого int значения, чтобы потом в формуле написать s = Math.Pow(hash,d) % n;

Comment: А, теперь вопрос ясен: как преобразовать byte[] в System.Double

Comment: Извините за это)). Может теперь смогу найти ответ

Comment: Да не за что. Была бы у вас OpenSSL - я бы решение сказал, но .NET не знаю

Answer (score 1):

Вычисление цифровой подписи RSA состоит из 3-х частей:

1. Вычисляем хэш от сообщения
2. Далее выравниваем длину хэша, чтобы он был равен длине RSA ключа (например тупо обрезаем или как-то дополняем с помощью [алгоритмов паддинга](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography))
3. К полученному выровненному *padded* хэшу применяем `h^d mod n`

Теперь более конкретно, применительно к вашему случаю: у вас есть md5 хэш - `026f8e459c8f89ef75fa7a78265a0025` - это его 16-ричное представление, его надо сначала обрезать согласно длины вашего ключа и перевести в цифру:

```
number = BigInteger.Parse(
    "026f8e459c8f89ef75fa7a78265a0025", //не обрезан
    NumberStyles.HexNumber);
```

Далее у вас есть число, с которым вы можете работать как надо.

Comment: Спасибо. Хотел бы уточнить, приемлимо без утрат данных подставлять в формулу такое число 9593692567689894420652...еще тут знаков 5. Это число я подношу к степени 29, а потом делают мод по 91, в итоге получил число 5(хм), похоже ли это на правду?

Comment: Да как я и думал, не работает так. Дело в том, что после мне надо проверить подпись. Для этого использую формулу h = s^e mod n. Использую BigIntenger, но на конце получаю не старый хеш, а уже другой который по значению очень сильно отвечает(31)

Comment: Это потому, что вы не обрезаете хэш - хэш не может быть длиннее длины ключа.